# local maven dependency crashes? what causes dependency version different from that in pom?

Tags: java, maven

In a project, it has maven module as following:

```
A -> A1, A2, module A has 2 sub modules A1 and A2.
A1 -> A2, module A1 has A2 as its dependency
```

by running `mvn dependency:tree` in A1, it shows following result:

```
[INFO] +- A2:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:7.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:jar:1.1.6:compile
```

running the same command in A2, it shows following result:

```
[INFO] +- co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:7.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
```

`jakarta.json-api` has wrong version in A1, and the hint is it is included from A2. However, in A2, hint shows it has no `version 1.1.6 jakarta.json-api`

This is result form git bash CLI, not any tool used. This is the first time I encoutered maven dependency behaves like this. all commands are run after `mvn clean`

This is A2 pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroup.ai</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>A2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yomahub</groupId>
            <artifactId>tlog-web-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

A1's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroup.ai</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>A1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>A1</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup.ai</groupId>
            <artifactId>A2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- I added this to make it right, although it does not have to be present -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yomahub</groupId>
            <artifactId>tlog-web-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--jasypt-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mygroup.ai.A.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I used a GUI tool to parse A1 pom.xml, it shows this:

```
A2: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT[compile]
- elasticsearch-java: 8.2.3[compile](omitted for conflict with 2.0.1)
- - jakarta.json-api: 1.1.6 [compile]
- - parsson: 1.0.0[compile]
- - - jakarta.json-api: 1.1.6 [compile](omitted for conflict with 2.0.1)
- jakarta.json-api: 1.1.6 [compile](omitted for conflict with 2.0.1)
jakarta.json-api: 2.0.1 [compile]
```

And used that tool to parse A2 pom.xml:

```
elasticsearch-java: 8.2.3[compile]
- jakarta.json-api: 1.1.6 [compile](omitted for conflict with 2.0.1)
- parsson: 1.0.0[compile]
- - jakarta.json-api: 1.1.6 [compile](omitted for conflict with 2.0.1)
jakarta.json-api: 2.0.1 [compile]
```

Comment: Please show the pom files of both projects..

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an old version of A2?Please, share both poms.

Comment: I think this is the reason. A has dependencyManagement limits jakarta.json-api (short as JJA) version to 1.1.6. And `elasticsearch-java` pom requires JJA 2.0.1 version and scope provided. Although A2 has 2.0.1 in pom.xml directly, ES brings 1.1.6. And A1 has A2 as dependency, A1 has 1.1.6 from parent, and both 1.1.6 and 2.0.1 from A2, so it decides to use 1.1.6. The odd part is ES pom JJA version does not work, which probably written somewhere on maven website: why provided version can be different from version required in pom.

Answer (score 0):

Maven resolves conflicting dependencies based on the nearest definition rule. A2 should be resolved using A as parent dependency in your case. Maven will use the version closest to the project declaring the dependency. You can explicitly control versions providing direct dependency or write exculsions on one of the dependencies.

Comment: The idiomatic way of enforcing versions of transitive dependencies it to take advantage of `dependencyManagement`